# Additional tab in custom module's admin configuration page

Tags: routes

Can't figure out why two admin pages of my custom module are not showing in different tabs. I've disabled and re-enabled the module, cleared cache, however while both pages are accessible and I see the "Leads" link in the menu, unfortunately they are not aligned into tabs. Can anyone help me to get my tabs?

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */

function leads_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/commerce/leads'] = array(
    'title' => 'Leads',
    'access arguments' => array('administer leads'),
    'page callback' => 'leads_active',
  );
  $items['admin/commerce/leads/subscribed'] = array(
    'title' => 'Subscribed Leads',
    'page callback' => 'leads_subscribed',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that first main path 'admin/commerce/leads' needs to be defined, and then other two items added.  The first item inherits the properties of the main menu item, and the second defines its own callbacks. Far from obvious, but it works for me now:

```
  function leads_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/commerce/leads'] = array(
    'title' => 'Leads',
    'access arguments' => array('administer leads'),
    'page callback' => 'leads_active',
  );
  $items['admin/commerce/leads/active'] = array(
    'title' => 'Active',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['admin/commerce/leads/subscribed'] = array(
    'title' => 'Subscribed',
    'page callback' => 'leads_subscribed',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access arguments' => array('administer leads'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. When in doubt, look at what Drupal core modules do. The Node module defines node, node/%node/view, and node/%node/edit.